# Visual Studio 2015 - How to reference a project from another solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I have Solution A which contains projects. They all implement only .net Core. Each project in A compiles fine.

Now, I have Solution B, whose projects depend on some solution A projects. Editing the project.json doesn't work:

```
"frameworks": {
    "dotnet5.4": {
      "dependencies": {
        "SolutionA.Project": "1.0.0-*",
        "SolutionA.AnotherProject": "1.0.0-*",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
      }
    }
  }
```

This project in Solution B won't compile. I get "`The dependency SolutionA.Project >= 1.0.0-* could not be resolved.`"

Is it true that we now have to add those SolutionA projects to SolutionB? I'm also confused because we can also do the old "Add Reference" and browse to the .dlls of Solution A's projects.

Solution A projects have been created as NuGet packages.

If there's anything I missed, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the other solution's `src` folder path to `global.json`. Something like:

```
{
    "projects": [
        "src",
        "../../OtherSolution/src"
    ]
}
```